# CSS - Facebook plugin overflows when displayed on mobile devices

Tags: css, facebook, iframe, overflow

I'm just starting out in web design/CSS so my current knowledge is limited.
With that in mind (this may be very easy for pros to fix), does anyone know why the Facebook iframe on this website won't stay within the sidebar on mobile devices?

http://www.northeastimage.co.uk

It looks great on desktop browsers but on the iPhone for example sits out of the sidebar over the margin sticking to the far right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

i would go for a user-agent to look trough your css and html, its a cross browser look also support phones and tablets it lets you "tell" the browser that your a phone tough your on your desktop

easy to debug while using it, i pref user agent for chrome get it **[here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=da)**

Get strings to view from more viewports than the standard amount that are embedded in the program